# Hudson build on URL token

Tags: continuous-integration, build-automation, hudson, build-triggers

I configured a hudson instance and have created jobs. While creating builds, I was able to see this option "Trigger the build by accessing this URL + SecretTOKEN" option. Now, I am unable to see that for any new jobs I create. Am I missing some setting or a configuration? The only change I made was running the servlet container from Root to a regular user.

Comment: What version of Hudson are you running?   Have you upgraded the install since you first created the jobs?

Comment: I am running the latest verion of hudson. Nope, I haven't updated or installed anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my Hudson (1.349) when creating a new job, there's an option under **Build Triggers** called *Trigger Builds Remotely (e.g. from scripts)*, which when selected allows you to enter an *Authentication Token* (which has the descriptive text from your question).

I'm not aware of any system configuration that disables this. It doesn't sound like a Hudson user permissions problem if you can have permissions to create/edit jobs.

What appears under Build Triggers when you create a new job?

Comment: It was not a problem with Hudson. Since I was running hudson as a different user, it wasn't able to get to its configurations. Hence, authentication wasn't working and those options were not being displayed. Fixed it now.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem with the missing *Trigger Builds Remotely* option. The fix in my case was to enable security in the main Hudson configuration (with *Anyone can do anything* selected)

Comment: How do I add the Trigger Builds Remotely check box to the job configuration? It is missing now. I am using Hudson 3.3.3.