# Hudson - missing Trigger builds remotely option

Tags: build, hudson, post-commit

I'm trying to set post commit build on Hudson but I can't enable Trigger builds remotely (e.g., from scripts) option in Hudson.

I have installed lots of plugins, google it for a while but all without success. This problem is kind of solved in (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2469831/hudson-build-on-url-token) but this doesn't work for me either.

My version of Hudson is Hudson ver. 1.378.

bets

Answer (score 9):

If security isn't enabled on the Jenkins instance, then the option is not available.

But that's because you can do: `http://jenkinsserver:8080/job/TestJob/build?delay=0sec`

Answer (score 5):

I am on Hudson 1.381 and I have this option under Build Triggers. So tell us more about you configuration. Do you have security enabled (on Hudson, not job level)? Did you check the log file?

Comment: It seems that you are on the right track - if you don't enable any security, then you can start the jobs without a token, and the option never appears. If you enable security, you then get the option.