# "Trigger builds remotely" does not appear after installing Build Token Root Plugin in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, slack-api

I have installed **Build Token Root Plugin (Version 1.2)** in Jenkins. But the "Trigger builds remotely" options doesn't appear.

The end goal is to trigger Jenkins from SlackBot. I followed this [tutorial](https://sonnguyen.ws/how-to-trigger-a-jenkins-build-from-slack/).

I must be doing something very silly. Please help.

Stackoverflow articles referred with no vain

[Hudson - missing Trigger builds remotely option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4285743/hudson-missing-trigger-builds-remotely-option)

[Triggering builds remotely in Jenkins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23223886/triggering-builds-remotely-in-jenkins)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to read it: [Quick and Simple Security](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Quick+and+Simple+Security)

- Enable the security setting, go to http://yourhost/jenkins/configureSecurity and select enable security, then choose Delegate to servlet container for security realm and Legacy mode for authorization strategy. Or, you may click on the Manage Jenkins link on the left side of the main Jenkins dashboard page to get to the configuration page, then click Configure Global Security.
- To log into Jenkins go to http://yourhost/jenkins/loginEntry, or click on the login link located on the top right hand corner of any Jenkins Dashboard page.
- This will bring you to the Login page. Enter the user name and password, and click on the Submit button. This will take you back to the main Jenkins dashboard. You will now see the Manage Jenkins link on the left side of the page.
- To logout simply click the logout link located on the top right hand corner of any Jenkins dashboard page.

> #### Anonymous read access required
>
> The preceding instructions require that anonymous users have read access to Jenkins. If you disable overall read access for anonymous users, the Build Token Root Plugin allows use of tokens.

Comment: Thank you Taun. I was facing the issue because I had basic auth included in my nginx reverse proxy. I removed it and followed your steps, and it is working fine.

Comment: @MunaiDasUdasin Glad to help you!

Comment: I locked myself out of Jenkins by doing that.

Answer (score 7):

Be carreful while applying the accepted answer. It locked me out of Jenkins.
Here is an alternative:
 * Security Realm: `Jenkins' own user database` (uncheck `Allow users to sign up`)
 * Authorization: `Logged-in users can do anything`

The “Trigger builds remotely” then appears.